# Is there actually an advantage to using Win API calls for file access?

Tags: c#, .net, api, windows, file-handling

I remember coding file access using the Win API about 15 years ago. It was much faster than using the FileStream of my language at the time (Delphi).

I spent a while today experimenting in C# under .Net 4.5, and I cannot see a real advantage to using the Win API. Most of the time the standard FileStream is faster, even with its buffering behavior (I know that used to add a substantial overhead a decade ago).

I've studied [this](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64538/tr-2004-136.pdf) research article by Microsoft, but it's over 10 years old now and not very applicable.

So my question is this: when is it advantageous to use the Win API as opposed to the standard FileStream?

Comment: Use the construct appropriate to how your team is developing.  If FileStream is standard for your team, then use that.  Only use a different technology if there's a compelling reason to do so.  Performance analysis should tell you if you need to look for something other than FileStream.

Comment: Why the down vote? No one is helped by an unexplained down vote.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "standard FileStream."  FileStream is merely a .NET object, an abstraction.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's part of my point. By "standard", I mean the one that is a standard part of the .Net library.

Comment: It's irrelevant, and implies that there is such a thing as a "standard way of doing it."  There isn't.  FileStream exists because it is a useful abstraction.  Use the Win API when you need to get under that abstraction and do something different.

Comment: You misunderstand my statement.

Comment: See [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/270208/1204), which explains one reason why you might want to get underneath the Stream abstraction and do something different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using .NET (particularly recent versions of .NET), a good guideline is to always use the built-in .NET functionality until and unless there is a marked benefit to doing otherwise. In other words: assume .NET is the right way to get the job done until you strongly suspect (or know) that it isn't. Nine times out of ten, the Framework (having been used so widely) will take into account checks and performance improvements that you won't consider.

It's really the same reason people say not to roll your own security solution if you can avoid it - because it's already been done by someone who is probably smarter than you and knows more about it, and other people have already tested it. The same applies to a widespread library like .NET. If someone has already done the work for you, and that work has been vetted by thousands or millions of users, why not go with that until you have a reason not to (such as it not providing the functionality or speeds you need).

Comment: It's really the same reason people say not to roll your own security solution if you can avoid it - because it's already been done by someone who is probably smarter than you and knows more about it, and other people have already tested it. The same applies to a widespread library like .NET. If someone has already done the work for you, and that work has been vetted by thousands or millions of users, why not go with that until you have a reason not to (such as it not providing the functionality or speeds you need).

Comment: The decision to use an underlying api is dependent entirely on your project's specific requirements.  Any answer that says otherwise is just guessing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey And his question was: how do you know if your project's specific requirements necessitate it? My answer was: you ought to assume they don't, until you encounter a specific problem that requires those API's to solve. Otherwise, you let the framework do the heavy lifting for you. Chances are, your need is not unique enough to require it's own solution.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is fair enough; I upvoted it.  You should add your comments about security to the actual answer.

Comment: @Locke I intend to use the standard .Net FileStream. I agree with your logic. But I'm still curious as to when not doing this is the way to go. This is now a curiosity question more than anything.

Comment: Post-.NET 3.5, I've never run into a situation that warranted it. As you mentioned, there were speed concerns in older versions of .NET, but the newer versions do a solid job of providing access to the file system. @mnn provided an interesting answer below, though: WinAPI provides support for longer file names.

Answer (score 4):

Using Win API, you can support long paths in your application:

> [PathTooLongException]: The specified path, file name, or both are too
> long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters,
> and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

For more information about using long paths in .NET applications, see this blog series:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton)

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you can basically assume they got it right.  Thus, the only cases where you can reasonably hope to improve upon the library answer is when you're doing something that's generating inefficiency.

Personally, I have seen only one case:  I had a file consisting of millions of integers that had to be read in and also updated in place, as well as a matching file of GUIDs where chunks would be read.